# "Objects are not valid as a React Child" on imports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, import

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import Firebase from 'firebase';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>App</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

So this code is crashing because of the import Firebase from 'firebase' I used 'npm install --save firebase' and I did 'npm link firebase' and firebase is in package.json, but that import is still crashing it. Anyone know why? I saw some people just created a variable for firebase, but it does this for all imports and I also need to add a google sign in import, which also crashed my app.

Comment: You are trying to render your App inside your App? You can't render objects like that in React, even I'm not talking about rendering itself.

Comment: Oops, no curlies there, sorry my bad. So, if you don't try to import Firebase, is the error gone?

Comment: yes without the import it's fine

Answer (score 1):

Configure firebase before running the app. Check the following link to configure firebase in Android or iOS.

https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.2.x/installation/android
https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.2.x/installation/ios